# How to insert multiple values in single CSV column using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a problem in exporting a csv file using php, all is well except products, i want all products in one cell, and products are coming from different tables, i tried with following code but could not get result as i expect, please help me.
thanks

```
ID    Status    Products        Buyer Name
1     Pending   book1, book2    bheem


$row = array();

$row[] = 'ID';

$row[] = 'Status';

$row[] = 'Products';

$row[] = 'Buyer Name';

$data .= join(',', $row)."\\n";

$query = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id='{$_GET['order_id']}'" );
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ); 
$row = array(); // We must clear the previous values
$row[] = $row2['order_id'];     
$row[] = $row2['status'];

//Browse product name
$product_q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM books WHERE bid='{$row2['bid']}'");
$res_prd = mysql_query($product_q);
$prow = '';
while($prows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_prd)) {   
    $prow.= $prows['product_name'];                     
}   
    $row[] = $prow; 

$row[] = $row2['buyer_name'];
$data .= join(',', $row)."\n";

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order.csv");

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");

echo $data;
```

Comment: what result did you get with this code ?

Comment: It would be indescribably helpful if you were you provide an example of the output you were hoping for as well as the output you ended up with

Comment: @Saiyam Patel I am getting every product in different cell, but i want all product in one cell, hope you get well, thanks

Comment: @Codemonkey Like, order id="0001", status="pending", products="book1, book2, book3", buyer="Codemonkey" ....

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id='{$_GET['order_id']}'" );
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
 $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {    

    $row = array(); // We must clear the previous values
    $row[] = $row2['order_id'];
    $row[] = $row2['status'];

    $product_q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM books WHERE bid='{$row2['bid']}'");
    $res_prd = mysql_query($product_q);
    $prow = '';
    while($prows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_prd)) {   
          $prow.= $prows['product_name'];                       
        }   //End inner foreach 
    $row[] = $prow; //End while 
    $row[] = $row2['buyer_name'];

    $data .= join(',', $row)."\n";
  }
```

Try like this... may be helpful :)

Comment: this is you logical problem with relation of the database...
$prow = $prows['product_name'];.... remove . from this line

Answer (score 0):

Using joins really makes this stuff easier.

```
$orderid = intval($_GET['order_id']);
$query = sprintf("SELECT order_id, status, product_name, buyer_name FROM books INNER JOIN orders ON bid = order_id WHERE order_id='{$orderid}'");
```

Now your query will get as a result an array containing:
order_id, status, product_name, buyer_name

implode your result and output the content and your done.

Comment: be aware, this creates a new line for every product.

Comment: sorry, this again creates new line for every product, is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ',' is the cell delimiter, and you are using ',' when you are listing the products, this pushes each product into a new cell.

I think all you need to do is change your while loop to this:

```
$prow = '';
while($prows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_prd)) { 
    if($prow === '') {$prow = '"';}//start escaping the cell
    else{$prow .=', ';} // separate each product by a space and comma
    $prow.= $prows['product_name'];//add the product name
} 
$prow .= '"';//finish escaping the cell
```

Escaping the products cell by wrapping it in double quotes will allow you to use commas inside that cell.